# C++ Array convert from 512x512 to 16x16x32x32

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 3d

I have an array which is 512x512 of ints ranging from 0-255.

I want to split up the 512x512 into 16x16 and in each of the 16x16; there are 32x32.

Visual Illustration:
[image: Visual]

Because I want to be able to compare a of the 16x16 blocks to another (so technically compare one 32x32 array to another 32x32 array).

Comment: I suggest using a predefined matrix library.  boost uBLAS comes to mind although I have not used it.

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt I'll be able to use that as this is a Uni assignment. We're using matrices (that's how I've created the 512x512), but I'm stumped on how to proceed.

Comment: So you already have a matrix class?  If so, isn't it just a matter of mapping indices?

Comment: The Matrix class has a constructor which accepts 2 ints (which are 512, 512 for the rows and columns) and a double pointer. I don't understand how I can develop this further.

Comment: I'm not sure what the double pointer is for.  Perhaps you can post some sample code.  Assuming your 512x512 matrix is populated, I suggest you start by trying to build a single 32x32 matrix from the content of your original matrix.

Comment: @AnonMail the double pointer was a 1D array, so basically the source of the data. Yeah sure I can post the matrix class? Do you feel it'd be better instead of creating a single 32x32, but make a 3D matrix? So: [x][y][z] where x is the 16x16 number, y is the 32x32 column, and then z is the row?

Comment: How you set up you data depends on how you want to manipulate the data (which you've stated) and what functionality you library or matrix class provides.  A 3D matrix may make sense if your matrix class provides an easy way to compare or access various dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate a proper 16x16 matrix of 32x32 matrices
and then enumerate your rows and cols from the 512x512 matrix.

For each row r and column c from the source the "address" with the
16x16 matrix is given by r/32 and c/32 ( "/" denoting integer division)
and the index values for the 32x32 matrix with the 16x16 slot addressed is
given by r%32 and c%32 /"%" identifying integer remainder operator.

If performance is an issue you might also exploit bit operations and replace "/32" by ">>5" and "%32" by "&0x1f".